# How to update model's table using a dicitonary in Django

Tags: django, database, dictionary, model, save

I can't seem to update the Results table in Django using a dictionary, it may be that i need to include the username as the key, but i dont know how to do this?

in func.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from .forms import SignUp
from .models import Table, Results
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .serializers import TableSerializer, SessionAvgSerializer, ResultsSerializer

curArr=[GBP,EUR]

def calc(curArr, user_results, username):
        results = {}
        specs = {'GBP': 1,'USD': 2, 'EUR': 3}
        for item in curArr:
                if item in specs:
                        results[item] = specs[item]
                for (key, value) in results.items():
                        setattr(Results, key, value)
                        Results.save()
        return(results)
```

in models.py

```
class Results(models.Model):
    Currency = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    Value = models.IntegerField()
    Units = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

To see the Results table updates with:

```
Username | Currency | Value | Units|

           GBP         1
           EUR         3
```

but i get this instead:
Results.save()
TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: No this isn't anywhere near right. You need to get the item from the database and update it; no need for `setattr`. But you'll need to explain a bit more what you are trying to do. What is the point of the `specs` dictionary? What are the 1, 2, 3 values? What are you intending to use to identify the item in the db - just the currency? the currency + username? And what is `units` doing?

Comment: i need to update the Results table with the currency option in the curArr array that has been looked up in specs and saved to results {}. So i need to update the Results table or db with that in results {} the spec values 1,2,3 are arbitary for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure what you are trying to do here - I don't know what the `username` or `user_results` arguments are doing, for example - but the basic idea is simple:

```
for currency, value in results.items():
    result = Results.objects.get(Currency=currency)
    result.Value = value
    result.save()
```

or you can make it a bit more efficient:

```
for currency, value in results.items():
    Results.objects.filter(Currency=currency).update(Value=value)
```

where there is no need to call `save()`.

**Edit**

Now you've clarified that you want to create new Results. So:

```
user = User.objects.get(username=username)
for currency, value in results.items():
    Results.objects.create(Currency=currency, Value=value, user=user)
```

Comment: The Results table has the fields: currency and value (as well as username and units). The result dictionary has the key-value pairs and is what updates into the currency and value fields of the Results table. So I think your solution is nearly right but doing something else :)

Comment: Doing what? This code is getting the Result object by the dictionary key, which is the Currency, and setting its Value to the dictionary value. Would it be clearer if I did `for key, value in results.items(): result = Results.objects.get(Currency=key)`? It's the same thing.

Comment: I'm not making myself clear, apologies. I simply want to add the results dictionary items to the Results table. So it is not getting anything but adding the currency request and the value

Comment: OK so these are items that don't already exist in Results, and you want to create them? If so, you'll need to supply a value for the `user` field, since that is not set to allow null values. I presume you want to find it from the `username` parameter?

Comment: yes that is correct, it can be found from the username parameter that is passed in the function